# Bootstrap - how to make modal not showing if the condition is false when clicking the button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In my web project i am using bootstrap. Everything goes smoothly except one case below:

In one page there is a button. when its clicked a JS function will be invoked to do some checking. If the checking fails, i hope only the alert message box shows up. However both the alert box and modal Div box show. Can someone help? Thanks a lot!

Below is the code i am using:

**button:**

```html
<button id="setPropertiesDivButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#setPropertiesDiv"
onclick='showSetPropertiesDiv(-1)'>Add Properties</button>
```

**Modal Div:**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="setPropertiesDiv">
........
</div>
```

**JS function:**

```js
function showSetPropertiesDiv(pageIndex) {
    if (!checkObjIsNull($("#oldPrice"))) {
        top.dialog_alert("Please set Price!");
        $("#setPropertiesDiv .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-footer .btn.btn-primary").hide();
        //$('#setPropertiesDiv').modal('hide');
        //$("#setPropertiesDiv .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-footer .btn.btn-primary").modal('hide');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button fires two events: opening the modal (Bootstrap event) and your event.

Remove the 'data-...' attributes from the button (this will always open the modal), remove all code that hides the modal in your javascript and open the modal with

**HTML:**

```
<button id="setPropertiesDivButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
onclick='showSetPropertiesDiv(-1)'>Add Properties</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function showSetPropertiesDiv(pageIndex) {
    if (!checkObjIsNull($("#oldPrice"))) {
        top.dialog_alert("Please set Price!");
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#setPropertiesDiv').modal();
    }
}
```